# convert quilt to native source package

Tags: package-management, packaging, patch

I want to branch an open source package and develop a new branch of package alternatively.

The package is in quilt format and need to use dquilt for update but i don't want to use it for my branch development.

I want to know if i change debian/source/format to native do i loss any thing?

Existing patches in debian/patches still apply to package or i lose them completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert it to `3.0 (native)`, then the quilt patches won't be applied.

You could apply them buy using `dh $@ --with quilt`, if the package uses `dh`, or manually calling the patch and unpatch commands during the build.